# the output is keep getting '0' value

Tags: vhdl

hi i'm new in vhdl and i'm trying to make a loop that change depending on the incremented value when clocked.
Here's is my code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity test1 is
    port (
        clock,reset:in std_logic;
        do:out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
    );
end test1;
architecture code of test1 is
    signal index:integer;
    signal indexbinary:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
    process (reset,clock) begin
        if(reset='1')then
            for i in 0 to 9 loop
                do(i)<='0';
            end loop;
        elsif(clock'event and clock='1')then
            for i in 0 to 5 loop
                if i < index then
                    do(i)<='1';
                end if;
            end loop;
            index<=index+1;
        end if;
                indexbinary <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(index, indexbinary'length));
        do(6)<=indexbinary(0);
        do(7)<=indexbinary(1);
        do(8)<=indexbinary(2);
        do(9)<=indexbinary(3);
    end process;
end code;
```

the indexbinary is just for printing the index in binary (bcuz i wanna check the value of the index). But the problem is when i keep clicking the clock, the index getting incremented, but the output didn't came out...
can anyone else know why?

i've tried to use while loop but i keep getting this error:

```
Error (10536): VHDL Loop Statement error at test1.vhd(22): loop must terminate within 10,000 iterations
```

even tho alr increment the value of i.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You do not specify what tool you are using. Have you tried to running this in a simulator? I suspect you are having problems trying to compile this for hardware. While loops are generally not suitable for synthesisable code. Did you draw a circuit diagram you expect before writing any code?

Comment: hiii, sorry that i didn't specify the tool. I'm using quartus to run the code and use something called fpga to see the output.
fpga is a smth like a board tht have 7 display segment, switches, led, etc, idk what else.

Comment: The error is from a synthesis tool there is no such restriction in the  language itself. The good news is neither one of these for loops are required. `if reset = '1' then do <= (others => '0');` eliminates the first. The  range of index is at least s –2147483647 and +2147483647 inclusive in all revisions of the standard. You never initialize index nor restrict it's range with a modulus arithmetic operation. As is this will always assign the lower 5 bits to '1', and if simulated will eventually cause an index overflow. There are no other assignments to `do(0 to 5)`.

Comment: `std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(index, indexbinary'length))` would cause an error in simulation at the first rising edge of clock. There's a subtle hint. Simulate your code. Tricky tries to suggest that you're code doesn't reflect useful hardware and you do not describe it's intended behavior.